# Android - Refer to main runnable from DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I'm implementing `Runnable` in my Activity class and have a thread that uses that runnable to get something from SQLite and put it into the activity.

The problem is I want to refer to that `Runnable`'s `run()` method from the context of a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`...If I try to do like this `Thread t = new Thread(getApplicationContext());` I get an error saying `The constructor Thread(Context) is undefined` but in my onCreate I can do `Thread t = new Thread(this);`

So how can I reference the Runnable from the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` context...Here is my code adapted for short:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener,Runnable {
Thread t = null;
onCreate()...
run()...
OnItemClick(...) {
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
.
.
.
alert.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Thread t = new Thread(getApplicationContext()); //this thing doesn't work because it gets the app context as context not as referencing a Runnable's run()
            //Here I want to reference the run() method above
            }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can do `MainActivity.this.run()`

Or if you want a Runnable, not run(), define this Runnable as a field in your MainActivity

```
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() { public void run() {...} }
```

Or make your MainActivity `implements Runnable` then you can refer to this runnable as `MainActivity.this`